# "fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, sfml

G++ can't seem to find the required header in include stage. Make produces the following error:

```
g++ -c -Wall main.cpp -IC:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/include
g++    -c -o matrix.o matrix.cpp
In file included from maths.hpp:1,
                 from matrix.hpp:1,
                 from matrix.cpp:1:
utils.hpp:6:10: fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

In the makefile I am manually specifying the include and lib paths:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -c -Wall
EXE = 3d_test
SFML_INCLUDE_PATH = -IC:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/include
SFML_LIB_PATH = -LC:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib
SFML_LINK = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

all: ${EXE}

${EXE}: main.o matrix.o maths.o
    ${CC} main.o matrix.o maths.o -o 3d_test ${SFML_LIB_PATH} ${SFML_LINK}

main.o: utils.hpp maths.hpp matrix.hpp main.hpp main.cpp
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} main.cpp ${SFML_INCLUDE_PATH}

matrix.o: utils.hpp maths.hpp matrix.hpp matrix.cpp
  ${CC} ${CFLAGS} matrix.cpp ${SFML_INCLUDE_PATH}

maths.o: utils.hpp maths.hpp maths.cpp
  ${CC} ${CFLAGS} maths.cpp ${SFML_INCLUDE_PATH}

utils.o: utils.hpp utils.cpp
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} utils.cpp ${SFML_INCLUDE_PATH}

clean:
    del *.o 3d_test
```

And the #include's are in a file like this:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
```

Things I've tried:

1. specifying the absolute path to SFML headers in the #include's

This then gives the following error:

```
g++ -c -Wall main.cpp -IC:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/include
g++    -c -o matrix.o matrix.cpp
In file included from utils.hpp:5,
                 from maths.hpp:1,
                 from matrix.hpp:1,
                 from matrix.cpp:1:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32:10: fatal error: SFML/Window.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <SFML/Window.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

2. adding the included headers to the recipe for each object file

Result is the first error message included.

What really confuses me is I have a similar project where this makefile:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -c -Wall
EXE = chess_ai
SFML_INCLUDE_PATH = -IC:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/include
SFML_LIB_PATH = -LC:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib
SFML_LINK = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

all: ${EXE}

${EXE}: main.o
    ${CC} main.o -o chess_ai ${SFML_LIB_PATH} ${SFML_LINK}

main.o: main.hpp main.cpp
     ${CC} ${CFLAGS} main.cpp ${SFML_INCLUDE_PATH}

clean:
    del *.o chess_ai
```

compiles fine without any issues.

So I'm just asking as to what more I can do to try and fix this

Comment: This is pure C++. C and C++ are not the same language.  Don't spam tags like that.

Comment: @UnholySheep Since the include path is added with `-I`, both the angle bracket syntax and the quote syntax will work (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html)

Comment: What does the directory structure look like inside of `C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/include`?  Specifically, is there an `SFML` directory that contains a `Window.hpp` file?

Comment: @0x5453 yes there is an SFML folder in include which has Graphics.hpp, Window.hpp and System.hpp. Like I said what confuses me is that I have this similar project with a makefile that's virtually identical and which requires the same SFML includes, and that compiles fine with no issues at all